# Using DateTime.SpecifyKind and NULL dates in SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I am trying to do the following in SSRS:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ADateTime.Value),"",
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(Fields!ADateTime.Value), DateTimeKind.UTC).ToLocalTime())
```

When I preview the report I keep getting **#error** when the ADateTime value is **NULL**.

All I want to do is if there is a date then format it accordingly or don't display anything.

If I remove the *DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse* etc. it works fine.

Thank you,
HH

Answer (score 0):

Try using SWITCH

```
=SWITCH(
        IsNothing(Fields!ADateTime.Value),"",
        True, DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(Fields!ADateTime.Value), DateTimeKind.UTC).ToLocalTime()
       )
```

If htat does not work if might be the IsNothing thinks the value is "something". In that case you could try using `Len(Fields!ADataTime.Value) = 0, "",`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately neither option worked for me, but I did find this: =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ADateTime.Value),"",System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Fields!ADateTime.Value))                                            Which seems to work OK. Although I am not entirely convinced it is the best way.